# Copying file from docker container to host using docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to mount a volume from my host machine to docker using docker-compose but not getting my file copied over from docker-container.
This is what i have.

```
volumes:
  - /tests/testResultsReport:/tests/testResultsReport
```

I have a file that is generated inside testResultsReport folder every time I run my tests and want my file to be copied over from docker container to my host.

I think I am missing something in understanding how it works so needs a little help.

I already checked that path /tests/testResultsReport exists in host.

Comment: can you try removing extra space before `:` ?

Comment: Did that but file isn't mounting

Comment: Just check if that file exists in the container. Ideally, it should be synced with host binded volume, couldn't see anything suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

Adding below command fixed my issue. I have to make it as absolute path by placing `.` in front of compose path.

```
volumes:
  - ./tests/testResultsReport:/tests/testResultsReport
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to remove the space before ':', and also make sure /tests/testResultsReport exists in the host.

Comment: Already removed and checked.